# Conversion of IRT logit discrimination parameter to factor loading metric

Tags: item-response-theory

I am looking for the correct formula to convert IRT discrimination parameters obtained from a logit-link model to a correlation metric. Because of the logit scaling factor (1.702), I am a bit unsure as to the correct formula.

In the case of a probit model it is simply $\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1 + \alpha^2}}$, where $\alpha$ is the discrimination parameter. But how precisely does this formula change for the logit-link discrimination conversion?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to track down the correct formula which is essentially the same as above except 1.00 in the denominator is replaced with 3.29, thus:

for a factor correlation metric (standardized) from a logit-link discrimination parameter

$\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{3.29 + \alpha^2}}$, where $\alpha$ is the discrimination parameter.

Comment: Can you please provide a citation?

Comment: See slide #6 in this link:
http://www.lesahoffman.com/PSYC948/948_Lecture6_Binary_Responses.pdf

Comment: I know both models are the same. I was asking about the loading to discrimination transformation. See page 144, table 2 of https://www.unc.edu/~dbauer/manuscripts/kamata-bauer-2008.pdf. I think the formula for probit always applies as the 1 is about the standardized latent factor variance, not the error variance.

Comment: Not sure what your question is Jim. You asked for a citation re: my example of factor loading from discrimination. But you want discrimination from factor loading I see. Your point about the 1 makes intuitive sense, but I don't know for sure without doing due diligence.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. That was a typo. I wanted loading from discrimination. You can rewrite the formula I referenced to solve for the loading and you'll arrive at the same formula for probit.

Comment: That makes sense to me given your point about the standardized latent factor variance.

Comment: I ran some IRT models using Bayesian software, checked old class notes, looked at the linked paper a little closer (paper focused on probit since binary/ordinal CFA uses tetrachoric corr which is probit-based) and I'm now certain that your original answer was correct (+1 your answer). Only note is $\pi^2/3$ does not work well for the variance of logistic in practice. $1.7^2$ works better according to a number of papers in the psychometric literature https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250185868_Teacher's_Corner_Origin_of_the_Scaling_Constant_d_17_in_Item_Response_Theory

Comment: To be sure, were you looking to confirm the value for the logit scaling parameter or the given equation for obtaining a factor loading from the logit-link discrimination parameter?

Comment: I was looking to confirm the latter.